# Difficulty in writing data to file in Ocean Script

Tags: cadence

The code below creates the file, but is not writing data to it.

```
p=outfile("outfile.txt" "w")
fprintf(p "write to out file")
```

Answer (score 1):

Cadence uses buffered IO for files, so to see your output you will need to explicitly flush the port like so:

```
drain(p)
```

The port will also get automatically flushed when you close it, so this is only necessary if you want to see intermediate output.